# How to convert string to time in android?

Tags: android, time

I am getting string from voice(Speech to text). When i speak time it's display e.g. **"530pm"**. I want to convert only time from string. e.g. **"530pm"** to **05:30 PM**. How can i achieve this?
Thanks in advance.

I try this code but not work

```
String s= "530 pm";
        SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm aa"); 
        try {
            Date date1 = dateFormat.parse(s);
            Log.e("Time", ""+date1);
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            Log.e("Error", ""+e);
        }
```

Comment: Your format looks like " SimpleDateFormat("hmm aa") "

Comment: It's output like "Thu Jan 01 17:30:00 GMT+05:30 1970". But i only want to "05:30 PM". @invisbo

Comment: Please search properly and you will get the answer.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Read SimpleDateFormat documentation (parse&format methods and pattern syntax).

http://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html

```
String time = "530pm";
SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("hmmaa"); 
SimpleDateFormat dateFormat2 = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm aa");
try {
    Date date = dateFormat.parse(time);

    String out = dateFormat2.format(date);
    Log.e("Time", out);
} catch (ParseException e) {
}
```

Answer (score 6):

```
final String NEW_FORMAT = " hh:mm";
final String OLD_FORMAT = "hh:mm:ss";
 String formatDate;
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat(OLD_FORMAT);
            Date d = null;
            try {
                d = sdf.parse(Value);
            } catch (ParseException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            sdf.applyPattern(NEW_FORMAT);
            formatDate=sdf.format(d);
```